# Cannot read property '0' of undefined while attempting to receive data which is not on server

Tags: react-native

I have the following problem: my app gets different types of lists from site with open api. Usually this lists look like this:

```
{
    "message": "accurate",
    "cod": "200",
    "count": 10,
    "list": [
        {
            "id": 625143,
            "name": "Horad Minsk",
            "coord": {
                "lat": 53.9,
                "lon": 27.57
            },
            "main": {
                "temp": 294.15,
                "pressure": 1021,
                "humidity": 88,
                "temp_min": 294.15,
                "temp_max": 294.15
            },
            "dt": 1566371346,
            "wind": {
                "speed": 5,
                "deg": 120
            },
            "sys": {
                "country": "BY"
            },
            "rain": null,
            "snow": null,
            "clouds": {
                "all": 75
            },
            "weather": [
                {
                    "id": 803,
                    "main": "Clouds",
                    "description": "broken clouds",
                    "icon": "04d"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 625144,
            "name": "Minsk",
            "coord": {
                "lat": 53.9,
                "lon": 27.57
            },
            "main": {
                "temp": 294.15,
                "pressure": 1021,
                "humidity": 88,
                "temp_min": 294.15,
                "temp_max": 294.15
            },
            "dt": 1566371346,
            "wind": {
                "speed": 5,
                "deg": 120
            },
            "sys": {
                "country": "BY"
            },
            "rain": null,
            "snow": null,
            "clouds": {
                "all": 75
            },
            "weather": [
                {
                    "id": 803,
                    "main": "Clouds",
                    "description": "broken clouds",
                    "icon": "04d"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 625504,
            "name": "Malyavshchina",
            "coord": {
                "lat": 53.92,
                "lon": 27.6
            },
            "main": {
                "temp": 294.15,
                "pressure": 1021,
                "humidity": 88,
                "temp_min": 294.15,
                "temp_max": 294.15
            },
            "dt": 1566371362,
            "wind": {
                "speed": 5,
                "deg": 120
            },
            "sys": {
                "country": "BY"
            },
            "rain": null,
            "snow": null,
            "clouds": {
                "all": 75
            },
            "weather": [
                {
                    "id": 803,
                    "main": "Clouds",
                    "description": "broken clouds",
                    "icon": "04d"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 619955,
            "name": "Vostochnyy",
            "coord": {
                "lat": 53.92,
                "lon": 27.58
            },
            "main": {
                "temp": 294.15,
                "pressure": 1021,
                "humidity": 88,
                "temp_min": 294.15,
                "temp_max": 294.15
            },
            "dt": 1566371362,
            "wind": {
                "speed": 5,
                "deg": 120
            },
            "sys": {
                "country": "BY"
            },
            "rain": null,
            "snow": null,
            "clouds": {
                "all": 75
            },
            "weather": [
                {
                    "id": 803,
                    "main": "Clouds",
                    "description": "broken clouds",
                    "icon": "04d"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 621667,
            "name": "Sokolyanka",
            "coord": {
                "lat": 53.87,
                "lon": 27.58
            },
            "main": {
                "temp": 294.15,
                "pressure": 1021,
                "humidity": 88,
                "temp_min": 294.15,
                "temp_max": 294.15
            },
            "dt": 1566371362,
            "wind": {
                "speed": 5,
                "deg": 120
            },
            "sys": {
                "country": "BY"
            },
            "rain": null,
            "snow": null,
            "clouds": {
                "all": 75
            },
            "weather": [
                {
                    "id": 803,
                    "main": "Clouds",
                    "description": "broken clouds",
                    "icon": "04d"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 622069,
            "name": "Sheypichi",
            "coord": {
                "lat": 53.87,
                "lon": 27.58
            },
            "main": {
                "temp": 294.15,
                "pressure": 1021,
                "humidity": 88,
                "temp_min": 294.15,
                "temp_max": 294.15
            },
            "dt": 1566371362,
            "wind": {
                "speed": 5,
                "deg": 120
            },
            "sys": {
                "country": "BY"
            },
            "rain": null,
            "snow": null,
            "clouds": {
                "all": 75
            },
            "weather": [
                {
                    "id": 803,
                    "main": "Clouds",
                    "description": "broken clouds",
                    "icon": "04d"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 621275,
            "name": "Stolovaya",
            "coord": {
                "lat": 53.87,
                "lon": 27.57
            },
            "main": {
                "temp": 294.15,
                "pressure": 1021,
                "humidity": 88,
                "temp_min": 294.15,
                "temp_max": 294.15
            },
            "dt": 1566371362,
            "wind": {
                "speed": 5,
                "deg": 120
            },
            "sys": {
                "country": "BY"
            },
            "rain": null,
            "snow": null,
            "clouds": {
                "all": 75
            },
            "weather": [
                {
                    "id": 803,
                    "main": "Clouds",
                    "description": "broken clouds",
                    "icon": "04d"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 8019783,
            "name": "Serebryanka",
            "coord": {
                "lat": 53.86,
                "lon": 27.6
            },
            "main": {
                "temp": 294.15,
                "pressure": 1021,
                "humidity": 88,
                "temp_min": 294.15,
                "temp_max": 294.15
            },
            "dt": 1566371557,
            "wind": {
                "speed": 5,
                "deg": 120
            },
            "sys": {
                "country": "BY"
            },
            "rain": null,
            "snow": null,
            "clouds": {
                "all": 75
            },
            "weather": [
                {
                    "id": 803,
                    "main": "Clouds",
                    "description": "broken clouds",
                    "icon": "04d"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 627318,
            "name": "Navinki",
            "coord": {
                "lat": 53.93,
                "lon": 27.55
            },
            "main": {
                "temp": 294.15,
                "pressure": 1021,
                "humidity": 88,
                "temp_min": 294.15,
                "temp_max": 294.15
            },
            "dt": 1566371362,
            "wind": {
                "speed": 5,
                "deg": 120
            },
            "sys": {
                "country": "BY"
            },
            "rain": null,
            "snow": null,
            "clouds": {
                "all": 75
            },
            "weather": [
                {
                    "id": 803,
                    "main": "Clouds",
                    "description": "broken clouds",
                    "icon": "04d"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 629962,
            "name": "Slepnya",
            "coord": {
                "lat": 53.93,
                "lon": 27.65
            },
            "main": {
                "temp": 294.15,
                "pressure": 1021,
                "humidity": 88,
                "temp_min": 294.15,
                "temp_max": 294.15
            },
            "dt": 1566371362,
            "wind": {
                "speed": 5,
                "deg": 120
            },
            "sys": {
                "country": "BY"
            },
            "rain": null,
            "snow": null,
            "clouds": {
                "all": 75
            },
            "weather": [
                {
                    "id": 803,
                    "main": "Clouds",
                    "description": "broken clouds",
                    "icon": "04d"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

But sometimes user can try to get a list, which is not on server. So, in this case response is:

```
{
    "cod": "404",
    "message": "city not found"
}
```

But I don't understand, how to handle this situation. I tried to add `cod` verification to my render method:

```
{ list && list.cod !== 404
              ? (
                <FlatList
                  data={list}
                  renderItem={({ item }) => (
                    <ListItem
                      onPress={() => {
                        const { navigation } = this.props;
                        navigation.navigate('Details', {
                          itemTitle: item.name,
                        });
                      }}
                      roundAvatar
                      title={item.name}
                      subtitle={item.weather[0].description}
                      leftAvatar={{
                        source: `http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${item.weather[0].icon}@2x.png` && { uri: `http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${item.weather[0].icon}@2x.png` },
                      }}
                    />
                  )

                      }
                  keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                />
              )
              : null
                }
```

But id didn't help. Also I tried to add it to my fetching part:

```
function fetchCityFromSearch(city) {
  return fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&apikey=8df903ce56f6d18245e72f380beb297d`);
}

export const searchCityRequest = cityName => function (dispatch) {
  return fetchCityFromSearch(cityName)
    .then(dispatch({ type: Actions.CITY_RESPONSE_REQUEST }))
    .then(city => city.json())
    .then((city) => {
      dispatch(getCityFromSearch(city));
    })
    .then((city) => {
      if (city.cod === 404) {
        return null;
      }
      return city;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      dispatch({ type: Actions.CITY_RESPONSE_FAIL });
      console.log(error);
    });
};

export const getCityFromSearch = result => ({
  type: Actions.CITY_RESPONSE_SUCCESS,
  result,
});
```

But it also didn't help, so, can you help me to solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

**UPD**

When I added quotes to 404 I got the same error. Here's the stack trace:

TypeError: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

```
This error is located at:
    in CellRenderer (at VirtualizedList.js:688)
    in RCTScrollContentView (at ScrollView.js:976)
    in RCTScrollView (at ScrollView.js:1115)
    in ScrollView (at VirtualizedList.js:1081)
    in VirtualizedList (at FlatList.js:632)
    in FlatList (at HomeScreen.js:110)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at HomeScreen.js:107)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at HomeScreen.js:97)
    in RCTSafeAreaView (at SafeAreaView.js:45)
    in SafeAreaView (at HomeScreen.js:56)
    in HomeScreen (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction (at SceneView.js:9)
    in SceneView (at StackViewLayout.tsx:899)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:151)
    in AnimatedComponent (at StackViewCard.tsx:93)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:151)
    in AnimatedComponent (at screens.native.js:71)
    in Screen (at StackViewCard.tsx:80)
    in Card (at createPointerEventsContainer.tsx:95)
    in Container (at StackViewLayout.tsx:971)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at screens.native.js:101)
    in ScreenContainer (at StackViewLayout.tsx:383)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:151)
    in AnimatedComponent (at StackViewLayout.tsx:379)
    in PanGestureHandler (at StackViewLayout.tsx:372)
    in StackViewLayout (at withOrientation.js:30)
    in withOrientation (at StackView.tsx:103)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at Transitioner.tsx:267)
    in Transitioner (at StackView.tsx:40)
    in StackView (at createNavigator.js:61)
    in Navigator (at createKeyboardAwareNavigator.js:12)
    in KeyboardAwareNavigator (at SceneView.js:9)
    in SceneView (at createTabNavigator.js:39)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at ResourceSavingScene.js:37)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at ResourceSavingScene.js:26)
    in ResourceSavingScene (at createBottomTabNavigator.js:121)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at screens.native.js:101)
    in ScreenContainer (at createBottomTabNavigator.js:111)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at createBottomTabNavigator.js:110)
    in TabNavigationView (at createTabNavigator.js:197)
    in NavigationView (at createNavigator.js:61)
    in Navigator (at SceneView.js:9)
    in SceneView (at SwitchView.js:12)
    in SwitchView (at createNavigator.js:61)
    in Navigator (at createAppContainer.js:429)
    in NavigationContainer (at App.js:53)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at App.js:51)
    in Provider (at App.js:50)
    in App (at withExpoRoot.js:20)
    in RootErrorBoundary (at withExpoRoot.js:19)
    in ExpoRootComponent (at renderApplication.js:35)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:98)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:115)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:34)
    at renderItem (HomeScreen.js:122)
    at FlatList._this._renderItem (FlatList.js:626)
    at CellRenderer.render (VirtualizedList.js:1733)
    at CellRenderer.proxiedMethod (createPrototypeProxy.js:44)
    at finishClassComponent (ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:11581)
    at updateClassComponent (ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:11508)
    at beginWork (ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:12874)
    at performUnitOfWork (ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:17276)
    at workLoop (ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:17316)
    at renderRoot (ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:17417)
```

Comment: Try changing `{ list && list.cod !== 404` to `{ list && list.cod !== "404"` if your sample response is correct.

Comment: Maybe you should surround your statement by parenthesis like this: `{ (list && (list.cod !== "404"))`

Comment: @SergeiMikhailovskii given that this stacktrace comes from the cellrenderer I think the error is rather coming from this line: `subtitle={item.weather[0].description}`. Can you log the value of `item` in the `renderItem` function to figure out value you're getting there that doesn't have a `weather` key?